# Two's Complement arithmetic of 2 negative numbers

Tags: numbers, twos-complement

I need to calculate (-13)(base 10) + (-14)(Base 10) using representation of complement 2's in 6 bits. I read [Wikipedia:Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) how to do it. I converted 13 to (-13): `10011` and converted 14 to (-14): `10010` and I just did the math normally and got: 100101, but the system that is checking my answers keep telling me it is wrong and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 6 bits for the results, you should use 6 bits when converting to two's complement.

13 is `001101` in base 2, so -13 is 110011. 14 is `001110`, so -14 is `110010`. Adding them:

```
  110011
+ 110010
--------
  000101
```

The result is 5.

Comment: Thanks, but why did you remove the carry? I need the answer to be in 6 bits, I am not sure if i can calculate using 8 bits and then just remove the first two.

Comment: The carry in 2's complement is just overflow and should be discarded

Comment: You can do the math in as many bits as you like and remove the top bits as long as the result fits in the remaining bits

Comment: 2's complement with N bits is the same as computing modulo 2^N, so any multiple of 2^N should be removed from the result. In this case 2^N = 2^6 = 16, and you get -13+(-14) = -27 = -2*2^6 + 5. The result should be 5 no matter how you look at it. You may find this interesting: http://jonisalonen.com/2013/mathematical-foundations-of-computer-integers/